# How to suppress INotifyDataErrorInfo validation for a Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifydataerrorinfo

I have a class implements `INotifyDataErrorInfo` I have some properties with Error Notification. for example,

```
public class Request : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    public string LineOfBusinessIdentifier
    {
        get { return  lineOfBusinessIdentifier; }
        set 
        { 
            lineOfBusinessIdentifier = value;
            ValidateLineOfBusiness();
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
      // ValidateLineOfBusiness() Implementation for validation.
}
```

This class is inherited by plenty of other classes. All works fine. Now i have one place i dont want to show the notification in the UI for a particular operation, and need the notification after the operation. Is there anyway i can suppress the notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if [ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesonnotifydataerrors(v=vs.110).aspx)  (introduced since .Net 4.5) is set to false, the binding doesn't check and reports errors. Default value is true

```
"{Binding Path=LineOfBusinessIdentifier, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}"
```

---

also possible to erase Validation.ErrorTemplate (to hide error notification in view) and reset it in trigger setter

```
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>

<!--need custom error template-->
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}""/>
```

*this doesn't disable validation, only hides visual indicator of error*

---

viewModel derived from Request can override GetErrors method (if it virtual) and disable LineOfBusinessIdentifier property notification under some conditions:

pseudo-code:

```
override GetErrors(string propertyName) 
{
    if (someCondition)
       return base.GetErrors().Where(prop != LineOfBusinessIdentifier)
    else
       return base.GetErrors()
}
```

Comment: @AbinMathew, double-checked: ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors is not a DependencyProperty so Binding doesn't work. But if validation logic is non-trivial shouldn't it be reported/not reported by GetErrors methods depending on some condition?

Comment: Override is the solution i am going for. That make my life easy. Thanks for your time.